# Regex function to split words and numbers in a hashtag in a sentence

Tags: python, regex, hashtag

I need a regex function to recognize a hashtag in a sentence, split the words and numbers in the hashtag and put the word 'hashtag' behind the hashtag. For example:

- Input: `#MainauDeclaration2015 watch out guys.. This is HUGE!! #LindauNobel #SemST`
- Output: `#hashtag Mainau Declaration 2015 watch out guys.. This is HUGE!! #hashtag Lindau Nobel #hashtag Sem S T`

As you can see the words need to be split after before every capital and every number. However, `2015` can not be `2 0 1 5`.

I already have the following:

```py
r"(#)([A-Za-z]*|\d*)", r" \1hashtag \2 "
```

With output: `#hashtag MainauDeclaration 2015 watch out guys.. This is HUGE!!  #hashtag LindauNobel   #hashtag SemST`

I already have the following:

```py
document = re.sub(r"(#)([A-Za-z]*|\d*)", r" \1hashtag \2 ", document)
```

With output: `#hashtag MainauDeclaration 2015 watch out guys.. This is HUGE!!  #hashtag LindauNobel   #hashtag SemST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text = "#MainauDeclaration2015 watch out guys.. This is HUGE!! #LindauNobel #SemST"
print( re.sub(r'#(\w+)', lambda x: '#hashtag ' + re.sub(r'(?!^)(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)', ' ', x.group(1)), text) )
# => #hashtag Mainau Declaration 2015 watch out guys.. This is HUGE!! #hashtag Lindau Nobel #hashtag Sem S T
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UNT5Wx).

The `#(\w+)` regex used with the first `re.sub` matches a `#` + any one or more word chars captured into Group 1.

The `re.sub(r'(?!^)(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)', ' ', x.group(1))` part takes the Group 1 value as input and inserts a space between a non-digit and a digit, a digit and a non-digit and before a non-initial uppercase letter.